# Executing Teradata SQL script from .net in Teradata mode syntax to get 2 result sets after creating a volatile table

Tags: sql, .net, teradata

I would like to execute a SQL script to TeraData to retrieve two result sets used for a datareader, but can't quite get the correct syntax and get errors such as:

"Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement". or "END TRANSACTION must be the last statement in a request." I've tried a few different approaches, but just can't get it working. I've tried adding BT and ET statements too, but no joy.

I can get it to run in Teradata Studio Express when using run as Individual Statements.

I'm using Session mode = TeraData

Here's what I'm trying to do.
1 - Create a VOLATILE table
2 - Return the count from that table
3 - Return the results from that table

See general script.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE FINAL AS
(
 SELECT X FROM BLAH
)
WITH DATA ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINAL;
SELECT * FROM FINAL;
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Are you submitting all 3 statements as a single request, e.g. one invocation of ExecuteReader? You can't do that. Submit the CREATE as one request and the SELECTs individually or together after the CREATE is committed.

Comment: @Fred I am submitting as a single request. Our project only allowed to the single call. We are preforming this method for MSSQL and Oracle connections, so would like to continue in same fashion.

Comment: Not possible to do in this manner. In Teradata, you don't need a  temporary table or additional resultset to obtain the row count for the result of a SELECT prior to retrieving the rows. You can use the RecordsReturned or RecordsReturned64 property of the TdDataReader, for example. Or if the SELECT is always createing a table with the same  structure (DDL) you could pre-define a Global Temporary table, which would be materialized via INSERT not CREATE.

Comment: @fred thanks for the feedback. Based on my research, I am coming to that same conclusion. For a SQL DataReader once you read the reader it's at the end of the resultset. If that's the case with the TDReader, I'm still unable to get the rowcount without binding to a Dataset/DataTable which isn't preferred because it's too intensive when I pull 5-6 million rows.  Global Temp isn't preferable, but may end up going that route. I appreciate the comments.

Comment: If you invoke TdCommand.ExecuteReader, it returns a TdDataReader object which will have the rowcount (RecordsReturned) properties set.